# OpenCV resize substantially different results between python and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, opencv, image-processing, interpolation

I'm currently working on a project dealing with thermal imagery and am having to do some resizing of the resulting image. I'm currently resizing in javascript (after sending data from web server), and this works really well, unfortunately a new requirement means I'm having to move this resizing over to the web server, using python.

I've done this, but when i'm resizing i'm now getting a 'triple overlapping image', which I don't get in the javascript side (see screenshot)

Python (Working Version)

```
nparr = np.frombuffer(temps, dtype=np.float32)
temparr = np.copy(nparr)
temparr *= (1.0/temparr.max())
// array comes in single dimension, reshapre to (width,height)
temps = temparr.reshape(int(temp_frame["width"]), int(temp_frame["height"]))
 socketio.emit("thermal_image", {'data':b''+bytearray(temps),'width':temps.shape[0], 'height':temps.shape[1]}, broadcast=True)
```

Javascript (Working Version)

```
let bytes = new Float32Array(msg.data);
let width = msg.width;
let height = msg.height;
var mat = cv.matFromArray(height, width, cv.CV_32FC1, bytes);
let dst_mat = new cv.Mat();
let dsize = new cv.Size(1000,1000);
cv.resize(mat, dst_mat, dsize,0,0,cv.INTER_AREA);
cv.imshow(canvas_name, dst_mat);
```

And the new python code, alongside the javascript used to display
Python (Not working version)

```
nparr = np.frombuffer(temps, dtype=np.float32)
temparr = np.copy(nparr)
temparr *= (1.0/temparr.max())
temps = temparr.reshape(int(temp_frame["width"]), int(temp_frame["height"]))
resized_temps = np.zeros((1000,1000), np.float32)
cv2.resize(temps, dsize=(1000,1000), dst=resized_temps, fx=0, fy=0,interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
socketio.emit("thermal_image", {'data':b''+bytearray(resized_temps),
   'width':resized_temps.shape[0],
   'height':resized_temps.shape[1]},
   broadcast=True)
```

Javascript (Not Working Version)

```
let bytes = new Float32Array(msg.data);
let width = msg.width;
let height = msg.height;
var mat = cv.matFromArray(height, width, cv.CV_32FC1, bytes);
cv.imshow(canvas_name, dst_mat);
```

As you can see the only difference is the resize being either in the javascript or the python, and yet the results are between really good, and pretty much useless.
I know this is something i'm doing wrong but can't for the life of me figure it out.

The images are of the same person, slightly different poses. The second image is using the python, movement can still be seen, and if positioned correctly the object in the scene can be seen.. 3 times.

[image: good_thermal]
[image: bad_thermal]

EDIT: Changed images to clearer ones

Comment: try replacing resized_temps = np.zeros((1000,1000), np.float32)  with resized_temps = np.zeros((1000,1000, 3), np.float32)

Comment: @AlexAlex unfortunately, that just results in a black image (tried using all 3 channels in the display, and each channel separately just to make sure). Although I agree that python opencv defaulting to 3 channels is likely the issue.
It's annoying because i'm sure i've come across this before in something else but i just can't remember what it was

Comment: Fixed, silly bug, this is why you don't work when tired

Comment: for future ref, I used elem.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.data) to show image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly bug but in case anyone else comes across it after a sleepless time like me i'll post the answer:

I was receiving in the data a flattened byte array, then reshaping to the shape (width, height). This worked fine when doing the resize in javascript as I sent again the flattened array to javascript and the resize was done (height,width). Which is how opencv takes its values.

When moving to python I forgot to change the reshape to (height, width) and instead was keeping (width,height). So when opencv did the resize we were interpolating in the wrong directions, resulting in the lines and the duplicate images.

So Solution,

change line 
`temps = temparr.reshape(int(temp_frame["width"]), int(temp_frame["height"]))`
`temps = temparr.reshape(int(temp_frame["height"]), int(temp_frame["width"]))`

and voila, opencv plays nice